# Multivariable Chain Rule Dependent Variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

Why is there no multivariable chain rule for **dependent variables**?

Also, if there is a composition of functions, say $$\psi=\phi(x(u,v),y(u,v))$$, then how can one find the partial derivative of  $\psi$ with respect to $x$? Is this a case where the variables are considered dependent?

Update: I get  that the Chain Rule allows us to compute $\partial \psi/ \partial u$, but how could I find $\partial \psi/ \partial x$ in terms of $\partial \psi/ \partial u$ and $\partial \psi/ \partial v$?

Comment: "Dependent" isn't a stand-alone property; it's always a case of "variable $A$ is dependent of variable $B$". In single variable calculus you can get away with not stating it, because by convention it's almost always a case of $y$ depends on $x$. In multi you have to be explicit.

Comment: That said, with the function you've written, the regular chain rule says how to compute $\partial \psi/\partial u$ in terms of certain other partials. Can you update your question to specify which partial derivative you'd want to see written in terms of which other partials -- again, using your formula for $\psi$ as the test case?

Comment: @JonathanZ supports MonicaC I get  that the Chain Rule allows us to compute $\partial \psi/ \partial u$, but how could I find $\partial \psi/ \partial x$ in terms of $\partial \psi/ \partial u$ and $\partial \psi/ \partial v$?